# A website cannot be loaded on Firefox

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, web

Last week, on http://www.mytvsuper.com/, the following worked on Firefox.

```
general.useragent.override.mytvsuper.com
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.2486.0 Safari/1537.36

general.appversion.override
5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.2486.0 Safari/1537.36

general.platform.override
Win32
```

This week, the above no longer works. After I have logged in, the page will keep loading permanently, and the full videos cannot be loaded. Only short videos, i.e. trailers and advertisements, can be loaded. Could the problem be solved? The site requires Windows, but I am using Linux, so I seek to bypass the requirement.

Comment: The requirements of an external web site are hardly under our (or your) control. Are you asking us to diagnose the site's useragent requirements?

Comment: The site requires Windows, but I am using Linux, so I seek to bypass the requirement.

Comment: It loads fine on linux, I used a windows chrome browser UA. I did not send it different appversion and platform, they aren't using that information, almost nobody does from my experience.

Comment: Then you should ask what your question actually is and not make people pull the bits out piece by piece. I don't speak chinese so I can't surf the site, but I just watched a short video on it using Chromium browser. Don't ask a technical site how to use the internet, it's up to you to learn that, every site is different.

Comment: please delete comments that are duplicates of your question content

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a web site and has nothing to do with unix or linux.